# How to get the number of lost packets using TCP in NS-3 ? (80211n + MIMO example)

Tags: ns-3

I am using this example : https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/examples/wireless/80211n-mimo.cc .
For UDP, there's a function called "GetLost()" in UdpServer that returns the number of lost packets but for TCP there's not. I ask if there's any solution to solve this please. Thanks

```
      /* Setting applications */
      ApplicationContainer serverApp;
      if (udp)
        {
          //UDP flow
          uint16_t port = 9;
          UdpServerHelper server (port);
          serverApp = server.Install (wifiStaNode.Get (0));
          serverApp.Start (Seconds (0.0));
          serverApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));

          UdpClientHelper client (staNodeInterface.GetAddress (0), port);
          client.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (4294967295u));
          client.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Time ("0.00001"))); //packets/s
          client.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (payloadSize));
          ApplicationContainer clientApp = client.Install (wifiApNode.Get (0));
          clientApp.Start (Seconds (1.0));
          clientApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
        }
      else
        {
          //TCP flow
          uint16_t port = 50000;
          Address localAddress (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), port));
          PacketSinkHelper packetSinkHelper ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory", localAddress);
          serverApp = packetSinkHelper.Install (wifiStaNode.Get (0));
          serverApp.Start (Seconds (0.0));
          serverApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));

          OnOffHelper onoff ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",Ipv4Address::GetAny ());
          onoff.SetAttribute ("OnTime",  StringValue ("ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=1]"));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue ("ns3::ConstantRandomVariable[Constant=0]"));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (payloadSize));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (1000000000)); //bit/s
          AddressValue remoteAddress (InetSocketAddress (staNodeInterface.GetAddress (0), port));
          onoff.SetAttribute ("Remote", remoteAddress);
          ApplicationContainer clientApp = onoff.Install (wifiApNode.Get (0));
          clientApp.Start (Seconds (1.0));
          clientApp.Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
        }        

    Simulator::Stop (Seconds (simulationTime + 1));
      Simulator::Run ();

      uint64_t nb = 0;
      uint64_t lost = 0;
      if (udp)
        {
          //UDP
          nb = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetReceived ();
          lost = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetLost();
          double window = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetPacketWindowSize();
          std::cout << "Window Size :" << window << std::endl;
        }
      else
        {
          //TCP
          uint64_t totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast<PacketSink> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetTotalRx ();
          nb = totalPacketsThrough / payloadSize ;

          /*need help here to get the number of lost packets using TCP Thanks*/

        }
      dataset1.Add (d, nb);
      dataset2.Add (d, lost);
      std::cout << nb << " Received packets" << std::endl;
      std::cout << lost << " Lost packets" << std::endl;
      d += step;
      Simulator::Destroy ();
    }
  plot1.AddDataset (dataset1);
  plot2.AddDataset (dataset2);
}
```

Comment: Simply compare `totalPacketsThrough` to the total number of packets that were sent?

Comment: Can you include the code section in your question, where you are installing the TCP application?

Comment: Hi @V-Red, thanks for your reply, i have included the code section where the application is installed. i need to know please how to get the total number of sent packets using TCP. or if there's any other solution to get the number of lost packets. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Tx" trace for the OnOffApplication to call a function every time a packet is transmitted -

```
void SourceUdpTrace(Ptr<const Packet> pkt)
{
  nPacketsSent++;
}
```

Inside main(), use the following Config::Connect statement to set up the trace and link it with `SourceUdpTrace`. This statement has to be placed before `Simulator::Run()`

```
Config::ConnectWithoutContext("/NodeList/*/ApplicationList/*/$ns3::ManualOnOffApp/Tx",MakeCallback(&SourceUdpTrace));
```

Once you know the number of sent packets, you can easily determine the number of lost packets by comparing it the value of `nb`, as found by your line of code - `nb = totalPacketsThrough / payloadSize;`

Comment: Hi @V-Red, i have changed 'ns3::ManualOnOffApp' with 'ns3::OnOffApplication' and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much again, you have teached me a lot of things about NS-3. that was very helpful.